# The instance of entity type 'Outlet' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core-3.1

I want to use AddRange() method while store employee salaries. But at the execution `context.context.EmployeeSalaries.AddRange(employeeSalaries);` I get the exception

> The instance of entity type 'Outlet' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Here is Method:

```
public bool PaySalary(List<EmployeeSalary> employeeSalaries)
{
    using (DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        context.EmployeeSalaries.AddRange(employeeSalaries);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

EmployeeSalary Class Structure:

```
public class EmployeeSalary
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public float SalaryPerDay { get; set; }
        public float Days { get; set; }
        public float PaidSalary { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public virtual Outlet Outlet { get; set; }
        public virtual User Employee { get; set; }
    }
```

Any suggestion how I can do it fastly?

Comment: Why do you AddRange inside of foreach? You either do .AddRange, or you do .Add in foreach

Comment: Sorry that was typo... Now I remove typo.

Comment: Your problem is that somewhere else you probably getting some Outlet that you trying to add now (same Id or something). You should either reference same Outlet you getting, or you should stop tracking changes using AsNoTracking() when you getting Outlets list

Comment: Can you guide me how I can stop tracking of Outlets using AsNoTracking() because I tried to use AsNoTracking(). But I could not implement that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that within your list of EmployeeSalary objects there are two or more that refer to an Outlet object that has the same key but isn't not exactly the same object. If you don't need to save the Outlet objects when you save these EmployeeSalary objects then you can possibly work around this problem by setting each EmployeeSalary.Outlet to null